# Raw string email with Zend Framework 2

Tags: email, parsing, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2

I don't understand how to parse raw email with ZF2?

In ZF1 it was:

```
$emailObj = new Zend_Mail_Message(array('raw' => $str_email));
```

And it was ok for me!

Now it should be:

```
$emailObj = Zend\Mail\Message::fromString($str_email);
```

or

```
$emailObj = new Zend\Mail\Storage\Message(array ('raw' => $str_email));
```

or maybe:

```
$emailObj = Zend\Mime\Message::createFromMessage($str_email, $boundary);
```

But nothing of these does not work for me!

Comment: You first example is the equivalent. When you say it doesn't work, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using ZF 2.5 via Composer. When I do

```
$emailObj = Zend\Mail\Message::fromString($str_email);
```

It works perfectly for me. This is my working code.

```
    // Create a Zend\Mail\Message object with our message
    $email = \Zend\Mail\Message::fromString($src);

    // Create our transport
    $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp();
    $options = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(array(
        'host' => $this->_opts['smtp_server'],
    ));
    $transport->setOptions($options);
    $transport->send($email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested with the most recent version of Zend Framework 2 after running into the same issue. This works now, at least:

```
$mail = new Zend\Mail\Storage\Message(array('raw' => $content));
```